# Что интересного можете посоветовать для глубокого изучения c++

Tags: c++

Что интересного можете посоветовать для глубокого изучения С++

Comment: Google, Yandex.

Comment: Три варианта: 1-й читать книги и практиковатся выполняя задачи постепенно наращивая сложность. 2-й поступить в IT ВУЗ. 3-й пойти учиться на IT курсы (но только не взлет/посадка, или просто взлет, а нормальные у которых обучение от года и больше). Было бы желание, а все остальное сложится.